# ASP.NET Dynamic Data & Membership (Roles)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, dynamic-data, roles

I am  trying to setup roles in a dynamic data website..
the problem is that i cant set it by simpy doing this.

```
  <location path="List.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Administrators" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

so even when i login as a role called "Member" it still alows me to go into List.aspx

can any one please guide me on this..

oh btw i am also using mvc on the same site

Comment: Can you please make this question a bit clearer - it's hard to understand what you're asking. You might find you get a few more answers then.

Answer (score 8):

Dynamic Data pages ignores all that jazz.

Look at the Secure Dynamic Data Project here:

http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=14473

...

Or there is another way which worked for me.

Change your location path to:

```
  <location path="Admin/<TableName>/List.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Administrators" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

And then (in your global.asax.cs file) change your dynamic data route to:

```
routes.Add(new DynamicDataRoute("Admin/{table}/{action}.aspx")
```

This allowed me to provide table level security. If that doesn't work just make a comment and I'll look into again.

Answer (score 0):

Your question as my friend said , needs more details ,
anyway

1. at first try to check whether you **enabled Roles** inside web.config or not .
2. Have you done this by **WAT** or not ? Try the alternative as a test .

3 . Set the authentication inside web.config to **Forms** .
    
hope to help
Regards
-MHM-